# Collection Info in Shader Nodes

Tags: shader-nodes

Is there a way to get some info of the collections an object is part of? A "Random per collection" value would be great, but I dont think something like that exists as an object can be part of multiple collections.

Is there something similar?

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible. You can assign custom attributes to objects and then access them through an attribute node, but this would require setting it up manually or through a script. The latter could also be used for randomization of the value. Additionally, this would also require specific handling for the case when one object is part of multiple collections.